# Java issue: Handling an argument as a file and reading it

Tags: java

So I'm trying to figure this one out. I have a file, let's say it's text.txt. I want to open this using "Open with.." in Windows. From what I've figured out, this Windows function is just passing the file path as an argument to the program. In Java, I have this at the moment:

```
import java.io.*;
public class program {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       File inFile = new File(args[0]);

    InputStreamReader fileIO = new InputStreamReader(inFile);
    fileIO.toString();
    System.out.println(fileIO);
    fileIO.close();
}

}
```

When I run it, I get this.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The constructor InputStreamReader(File) is undefined
    at program.main(program.java:8)
```

I have put the file path in the run configuration and not even my Google Fu is working on this one. I'm quite tired tho, so I'll just leave this here for now.

EDIT: Apparently the superclass is java.lang.*, but whatever, that shouldn't matter(?)

Comment: Your Google Fu must really be out of order. Mine gave that : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-io/inputstreamreader.html

Comment: Update:
I went for a BufferedReader instead, as that seemed to be more what I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `FileInputStream`

```
InputStreamReader fileIO = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inFile));
```

because `InputStreamReader` does not have a constructor that takes a file argument.

Comment: Awesome! That was quick. I still don't get any output though, but I can work with it from here!

Answer (score 0):

[InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html) has no constructor which takes a `File` object as an argument.

Use the following code instead -

```
InputStreamReader fileIO = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(inFile));
```

Read the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html#FileInputStream%28java.io.File%29).

If you don't mind Apache Commons library, then there is a [more simpler way to do this](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29) -

```
File inFile = new File(args[0]);
String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(inFile);
System.out.println(content);
```